# How do you open a pre-designed DB with Cordova?

Tags: javascript, cordova, webview

I have a db file, and a path to the database file (sqlite3).

I was trying to pass that file into cordova, but i couldnt see how it is working.

According to cordova, openDatabase() has 4 variables.  ex:

```
var shortName = "testDB";
var version = "1.0";
var displayName = "testDB";
var maxSize = 835456;

var db = openDatabase(shortName,version,displayName,mazSize);
```

Could i pass in the path to the db file?  ex:

```
var shortName = '/var/mobile/Applcations/.../Application Support/com.my.project/someDb.db';
```

or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Cordova uses the [Web SQL Database](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/).
`shortName` is the name for the database, not the path of some file.
You will have to script something that "migrate" your data from your db file to your Database using the `transaction` method of the API. Here is an example for an insert:

```
db.transaction(function (tx) {
      tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO YOUR TABLE (columns) VALUES (values)");
});
```

Comment: After looking at the information, shortName is indeed the name of the db in reference to the file 0000000000001.db according to Databases.db (the organizing db of cordova).  There is a table in there, called Databases, which has the guid, origin_folder, name, displayName, estimatedSize, and path.

What if you open Databases.db, and modify the path to instead point to 0000000000001.db, /var/mobile/Applcations/.....

Comment: It isnt as much as a link as it is deconstructing what Cordova does.  I am working on a plugin to resolve this.  Ill post an answer when i have it working correctly.   openDatabase will create a entry in the Databases.db and then point to stuff.... so i am working to modifiy that stuff and see if I can adjust where stuff points

Comment: I was thinking that since Cordova uses webSQL, it would be able to link stuff?   I was trying to modift the path/origin data to try to get it to instead of opening file__0/00000000.db, it would open ../Application/something\ awesome/BundleIdentifier/myDb.db